# I have an older Dell laptop and the display to an external monitor is bad

Tags: graphics, external-display, dell-latitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I upgrade my laptop’s video RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/476112/can-i-upgrade-my-laptops-video-ram)

I have an older Dell laptop and the display to an external monitor is bad. It has lines and flickers and doesn't look good on a monitor.  Is it possible to replace the graphics chip?  If so, how and with what?  I'm running Windows XP.

Comment: Have you performed troubleshooting steps like trying a different monitor etc?

Comment: Check cables, check that there are no bent pins in the connector, ... I had a monitor that would work right _only_ if the (supposedly symmetric!) cord was in a particular orientation.

Comment: On most laptops the graphics chips are soldered onto the motherboard and you can not replace it. There are a few exceptions (e.g. laptops with MXM, or gaming laptops with graphical card(s) in miniPCIe slots. However without knowing the exact model we can not give you a definite answer on its replaceability.

Answer (score 0):

Is integrated in the mobo. You will need to replace the mobo. Alternatively you can try a USB to VGA adapter and use that instead. It may take a bit more resources but you will be able to work on this older system.